# Questions on setting up proper mappings when applying first isomorphism theorem for rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The first isomorphism theorem is usually stated in the following form:

> Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be a surjective homomorphism of rings with kernel $K$.  Then the quotient ring $R/K$ is isomorphic to $S$, and $K = kernel f$.

In the proof of the theorem, there usually appears a function such as $\phi(a + K)=f(a)$.  I am trying to apply the first isomorphism theorem to solve the following problem by imitating the strategy from its proofs.  I have to show that $Z_{20}/(5)\cong Z_{5}$.  So I let $f:Z_{20}\rightarrow Z_{5}$ be defined by $f(a+Z_{20})=a+Z_{5}$ and since $Im(f)=a+Z_{5}$ and $kernel f =\{[0]_5, [5]_5, [10]_5, [15]_5\}$.  At this point, do I just define the function $\phi(a+ ker f)=Im(f)=a+ Z_{5}$. Is this the proper way going about the solution?  The reason I am asking is because in many (not all) instances where i see the application of first isomorphism theorem is use.  I see an explicit function $f$ being written out mapping from $R$ to $S$ or to $Im(f)$ being set up, then the kernel is found of $f$ is described and then by the isomorphism theorem, it is solved.  The solutions usually skips the step of writing out explicitly the the function $\phi(R/K) = Im(f)$   Also, I am just wondering why that is. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your notation is not good: “$a+Z_{20}$ doesn’t make sense: $Z_{20}$ is the whole ring you are working in! What are your definitions of $Z_n$? Is it $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$? In that case, you wnt $a+20\mathbb{Z}$ and $a+5\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Note: the “right” way to use the First Isomorphism Theorem to show that $R/I$ is isomorphic to $S$ is *not* to try to define the map from $R/I$ to $S$ following the argument of the proof, but instead to define a surjective map $R\to S$ and then prove its kernel is $I$.The whole point of the Isomorphism Theorem is that once you prove it, you do **not** need to write out the explicit function $R/I\to S$: you can just invoke the theorem to know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “gold standard” way to apply the First Isomorphism Theorem to prove that a quotient $R/I$ is isomorphic to $S$ is to first define a surjective morphism $f\colon R\to S$, and then prove that $\mathrm{ker}(f)=I$. Then the First Isomorphism Theorem does all the work for you. The reason you never see the map $\Phi$ in the applications is that you don’t want to go through the every step of the proof each time you want to apply the theorem. That’s the whole point of proving the theorem in the first place!

Your notation leaves something to be desired. The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ do not look like $a+\mathbb{Z}_{20}$: that doesn’t even make sense, as you never write an element of a ring $R$ as $a+R$. I’m going to guess that you define $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as the quotient $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, so that elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ are of the form $a+20\mathbb{Z}$ with $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, and the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ are of the form $b+5\mathbb{Z}$, with $b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So, to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/\langle 5+20\mathbb{Z}\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$, we want to define a morphism $\mathbb{Z}_{20}\to\mathbb{Z}_5$ whose kernel will be exactly $\langle 5+20\mathbb{Z}\rangle$.

Your definition works. But you need to show that it is a ring homomorphism in order to use the Theorem. Once you prove it is a ring homomorphism, the fact that the kernel is precisely $$\{0+20\mathbb{Z}$, 5+20\mathbb{Z}, 10+20\mathbb{Z},15+20\mathbb{Z}\} = \langle 5+20\mathbb{Z}\rangle$$
gives you the desired isomorphism, via the Isomorphism Theorem. The isomorphism is going to be annoying to write, since the elements of the quotient group are cosets of cosets... It would look something like
$$\Phi\Bigl((a+20\mathbb{Z})+\langle 5+20\mathbb{Z}\rangle\Bigr) = a+5\mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanations.  This is what I understand from your answer.  To show isomorphism involving quotient rings and its image. I need to just create a surjective homomorphism map and also find the kernel and show that it is an ideal.  Then the first isomorphism theorem will do rest of the work for me.  In the case of my question,  The surjective homomorphic map would be: $f([a]_{20})=[a]_5$ and the kernel is: $<5+[a]_{20}>$.  Then I don't need to write out an explicit map from the quotient ring from $Z_{20}/(5)$ to $Z_5$ like...

Comment: the map:  $$\Phi\Bigl((a+20\mathbb{Z})+\langle 5+20\mathbb{Z}\rangle\Bigr) = a+5\mathbb{Z}.$$ which you wrote in the end.
Also, are the notation $n\mathbb{Z}$ and $(n)$ both denote the concept of ideals for the case of $mod n$, or is it respectively $<n\mathbb{Z}>$ or $<n>$.  Notations for denoting $mod n$ as rings are equally confusing, I sometimes see $Z_n$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @SethMai: Kernels of ring homomorphisms are *always* ideals. You don't "need to show [the kernel] is an ideal" if you show the function is a ring homomorphism. Given your notation, your description of the kernel of $f$ is still incorrect. The correct kernel is $\langle [5]_{20}\rangle$, not "$5+[a]_{20}$", which is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$. Likewise, it would not be "$Z_{20}/(5)$", but $Z_{20}/([5]_{20})$. Notation needs to be defined. That's why I asked you what *your* definition is. There are multiple ways of describing the ring of integers modulo $n$.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanations.